# Customizing the reminder.

Tags: customization, samsung-galaxy-note-3, alerts

Currently, the reminders are carried out by a one-time vibration (which is too easy to miss)

What settings do you go to to make them say, do 5 loud beeps or something?

This is for note 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more reminders for one single event.
If you want something more "loud" you should edit the notification sound to something like a longer notifications sound so that it will vibrate for all the sound duration.

Comment: Thank you matt95. I appreciate your answer. Could you be specific in how to do that? I got the Google keep app which is totally promising. But the darn reminders vibrate only once. It's a joke - except it is not funny.  It beats the heck out of me that simply being able to change the default behaviour of system reminders/alerts requires me to set up this stack exchange question. How do you reach the reminders setting  (or alerts or whatever it is called on android) so that the system reminders are done the way you want them to be done?

Comment: I see, Google Keeps unfortunately will let you add only one reminder per task, I'm using the HTC's one and it works great for me. If you want to get more vibration you should migrate to another app. The only thing you could do is, as i said above, set a longer alarm song so that you can at least hear it.

Comment: we'll do. could you tell me how I can set that up. under which menu item under the settings do I need to go? On my note 3, I tried device>notif panel. No luck. tried Device > Sound > XXX. no luck.

Comment: I've never had a Samsung device, however I suggest you to check out this link here http://www.samsung.com/us/support/howtoguide/N0000006/16522/224697